# Using custom classes in Spark on datasets and dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-types

I put together some custom classes I would like to use as native datatypes is SparkSQL. I see UDTs just got opened up to the public, but they are quite hard to figure out. Is there any way I'd be able to do this?

**Example**

```
case class IPv4(ipAddress: String){
  // IPv4 converted to a number
  val addrL: Long = IPv4ToLong(ipAddress)
}

// Will read in a bunch of random IPs in the form {"ipAddress": "60.80.39.27"}
val IPv4DF: DataFrame = spark.read.json(path)
IPv4DF.createOrReplaceTempView("IPv4")

spark.sql(
    """SELECT *
     FROM IPv4
     WHERE ipAddress.addrL > 100000"""
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a `Dataset` and filter using the case class `addrL` attribute:

```
case class IPv4(ipAddress: String){
  // IPv4 converted to a number
  val addrL: Long = IPv4ToLong(ipAddress)
}

val ds = Seq("60.80.39.27").toDF("ipAddress").as[IPv4]

ds.filter(_.addrL > 100000).show
+-----------+
|  ipAddress|
+-----------+
|60.80.39.27|
+-----------+
```